# Spring OAuth2 Redis Client Details

Tags: spring, redis, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I have a working example of oauth2 and rest with inmemory authentication and authorization for the client and owner of the resource.

I want to use Redis and is a bit confused on how to it set it up.

How to adjust my code below to be able to persist data in **Redis** (**e.g** token, refresh_token and other client details)

```js
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${spring.oauth2.realm.id}")
    private String REALM;

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("client001")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .secret("secret")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120) 
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.realm(REALM + "/client");
    }

}
```

**[Updated]**

I was able to store the tokens to **Redis** by utilizing **RedisTokenStore**. To do so, in your **OAuth2SecurityConfiguration** replace the following lines:

```html
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new InMemoryTokenStore();
}
```

with...

```html
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore(final RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
    return new RedisTokenStore(factory);
}
```

Now a new problem was encountered, in **`AuthorizationServerConfiguration#configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients);`**. Is there a support for **redis**?

```html
@Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
      clients.inMemory()
        .withClient("client001")
        .secret("secret")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
        .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
        .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
        .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60) 
        .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(120);
    }
```

When I peeked at **ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer** it only supports **inMemory()** and **jdbc()**. I was planning to use **withClientDetails()** to support redis. Is there a **RedisClientDetailsService** or something of the like?

Any comments and suggestion for its implementation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to store the client details to Redis.

These are the steps that I made:

1. Create the following classes:

   - RedisClientDetailsServiceBuilder.java
   - RedisClientDetailsService.java

**RedisClientDetailsService**

```js
public class RedisClientDetailsService implements ClientDetailsService {

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();

    private Map<String, ClientDetails> clientDetailsStore = new HashMap<String, ClientDetails>();

    public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(final String clientId) throws ClientRegistrationException {
        final ClientDetails details = clientDetailsStore.get(clientId);
        if (details == null) {
            throw new NoSuchClientException("No client with requested id: " + clientId);
        }
        return details;
    }

    public void setClientDetailsStore(final Map<String, ? extends ClientDetails> clientDetailsStore) {
        this.clientDetailsStore = new HashMap<String, ClientDetails>(clientDetailsStore);
    }

    /**
     * @param passwordEncoder the password encoder to set
     */
    public void setPasswordEncoder(final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }
}
```

**RedisClientDetailsServiceBuilder**

```js
public class RedisClientDetailsServiceBuilder extends ClientDetailsServiceBuilder<RedisClientDetailsServiceBuilder> {

    private Map<String, ClientDetails> clientDetails = new HashMap<String, ClientDetails>();

    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder; // for writing client secrets

    public RedisClientDetailsServiceBuilder passwordEncoder(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void addClient(
            final String clientId,
            final ClientDetails build) {

        clientDetails.put(clientId, build);
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientDetailsService performBuild() {
        final RedisClientDetailsService redisClientDetailsService = new RedisClientDetailsService();
        if (passwordEncoder != null) {
            // This is used to encode secrets as they are added to the database (if it isn't set then the user has top
            // pass in pre-encoded secrets)
            redisClientDetailsService.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        }

        redisClientDetailsService.setClientDetailsStore(clientDetails);
        return redisClientDetailsService;
    }

}
```

2. Then on **AuthorizationServerConfiguration#configure()**, set client builder with the builder we made.

```js
@Override
public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    final RedisClientDetailsServiceBuilder builder = new RedisClientDetailsServiceBuilder();
    clients.setBuilder(builder);

    // @formatter:off
    builder.withClient("client001")
          .secret("secret")
          .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
          .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
          .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
          .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120)
          .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(400)
    // @formatter:on
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just simply use an in-memory client here? Your implementation shows no usage of Redis.